# Struggling with Android Timers

Tags: android, timer

Hi there I am trying to start to make a android app (Beginners Stuff) and **i want whatever the user inputs in to the textbox to go to the textview that I have** I have started my code by referencing all of the ids and have searched all around the internet but every time I try it i just get errors can some one help me with some simple code that can do that.

```
public class BitActivity extends Activity {

EditText INPUT;
TextView byte1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bit);

    INPUT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
    byte1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.byte1);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

  }
```

Comment: see http://android-developers.blogspot.ie/2007/11/stitch-in-time.html

Comment: Where is your code you have written to set Textview text and get it from EditText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in your onCreate after you do your findVIewById

```
INPUT.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        byte1.setText(blah.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
```